# Returning multiple tables using JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, html-table

Is there a method or something else I'm missing or is my json data not structured correctly to get the result I want?

I'm trying to create several tables distinguished by a particular "part" and having rows with descriptions and values. The image shows what I've been able to accomplish so far. The tableTimesHeaders variable works in that I'm able to create as many tables are there are "part" in the json data, but then I end up iterating through everything when I try to map for  rows. I include {rows} in the tableTimesHeader return and I end up with all descriptions and values in each table. For each table related to a part, I only want the descriptions related to that part so that each table is part specific. I've tried nesting my json data further and mapping in different ways. Thank you for any input!

[image]

This is what my json data looks like

```
[
    {
        "part":"supercharger",
        "torqueSpecs":[
            {"description":"Coolant pump to supercharger","value":30},
            {"description":"Supercharger to engine block M8","value:18"},
            {"description":"Supercharger to engine block M10","value":33},
            {"description":"Supercharger outlet pipe to supercharger","value": 18},
            {"description":"Coolant pump to engine block", "value": 22},
            {"description":"throttle valve assembly to supercharger intake duct", "value": 7}
        ]
    },
    {
        "part":"starter",
        "torqueSpecs":[
            {"description":"Field strap to starter","value":10},
            {"description":"Alternator lead to starter motor","value":10},
            {"description":"Heat shield to starter motor","value":7},
            {"description":"Wiring to starter solenoid", "value": 6}
        ]
    }
]
```

And this is what my component looks like in React.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Table, Button, Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import data from './torqueSpecs.json'


const TorqueSpecs = () => {

    let rows

    rows = data.map(obj => obj.torqueSpecs.map(torqueSpec => {    
    
        
            return (
            <tr>
                <td>{torqueSpec.description}</td>
                <td>{torqueSpec.value}</td>
            </tr>  
            )
    }))

    let tableTimesHeaders

    tableTimesHeaders = data.map(obj => {

        return (
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{obj.part}</th>
                        <th>values</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {rows}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        )
    })
            

        return(
            <>
            <Container>
                {tableTimesHeaders}
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}

export default TorqueSpecs
```

Comment: I believe the ReactJS tag was more important than HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

Since the `rows` should only contain the data for each "part" you should populate it inside the second map and derive it from the `obj`.

Something like this

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Table, Button, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import data from "./torqueSpecs.json";

const TorqueSpecs = () => {
  const tableTimesHeaders = data.map((obj) => {
    // only use the torqueSpecs of the specific obj
    const rows = obj.torqueSpecs.map((torqueSpec) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{torqueSpec.description}</td>
          <td>{torqueSpec.value}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return (
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>{obj.part}</th>
            <th>values</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Container>{tableTimesHeaders}</Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default TorqueSpecs;
```

Comment: Ah I see. So in other words, the second map is an iteration within the iteration, in which case for part:supercharger, it iterates each supercharger description and {rows} ends up showing it for that particular table? Thank you